# Approximation of plane curve with tangent vector

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, curves, tangent-line

Let $c:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ a $\mathcal{C}^1$ planar curve and suppose that $c(0)=(0,0)$ and $c'(0,0)=(a,0)$, $a>0$. I'm trying to prove the following statement (without any success): there exist $m,q>0$ such that the curve $c$ is contained in the triangle of vertices $(0,0),(q,mq),(q,-mq)$ for every $t$ in a sufficiently small right neighborhood of $0$.

Intuitively it has to be true since tangent vectors approximate the curve locally, but how to prove it rigorously?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is only true in a neighborhood of $0^+$, that is to say an interval $(0,\varepsilon)$.

Comment: Yes, it should be true in a right neighborhood of $0$ but how to prove it?

Comment: Use Taylor's theorem of order 1 with Peano remainder https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If it will became an answer I surely give an upvote to it.

Comment: It is only a hint, I don't want to solve the problem for you. Consider the coordinates $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ of $c(t)$ and apply the formula to these coordinates, with order $k=1$